# How to post message on Facebook wall with PHP API from local server?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I post a message on my Facebook wall with PHP API from a local server?
I use local PHP server Apache.

Please, give me an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats possible of course. Where you run your PHP is unimportant. You need just an accesstoken for your profile to do so. Maybe you have to set the url of the facebook application in the developer center to your localhost url.

Comment: I use example from Facebook SDK - /examples/example.php. I open this file in my browser locally. In page, I press link "Login with Facebook". And redirecting on Facebook Auth Page. And get error API Error Code: 191
 API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
 Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri:

P.S. My file with example put in localhost/graph.api/examples/example.php

Comment: That's probably because your app settings on facebook say your app lives somewhere other than localhost.

Comment: Correct! That is what I tried to describe. You have to set an URL for your facebook application in the application settings. So there you would have to point to http://localhost/my-facebook-app/ or whatever URL your running your demo website on your personal computer.

Comment: And how to put in  "localhost/my-facebook-app" my PHP-SDK to play sample? What should be the directory structure and files in  "localhost/my-facebook-app"

Comment: when you already got the auth dialog you gone right until this place. that means that your SDK is correctly included and working. what exactly is your URL your localhost script is running on? do you have also set this url to the application settings on facebook in the "application with facebook" (or so) section?

Answer (score 2):

You call the `/me/feed` connection and the proper parameters called in the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)

```
$parameters = array('message' => 'Test message');

$facebook->api('/me/feed/','post', $parameters);
```